# How to make the Column Footer band dynamically hide in Jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report made in ***iReport***. I included a `textFieldExpression` in the column footer. My problem is that even though the line is blank it still takes up the space of the height of the band and thus sending the rest of fields to another sheet.

The code that I have is the following:

```
<columnFooter>
    <band height="12" splitType="Stretch">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{descripcionComentario}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="42" y="0" width="100" height="12" uuid="5a9cbe9d-486a-4dd4-a865-d421cd7366a6"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="8"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{descripcionComentario}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</columnFooter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `columnFooter` is [**not resizable at run time**](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/report-structure-jaspersoft-studio), you need to find another report structure to solve your issue.

The solution often is to use groups where you have access to the `groupFooter` band.

Comment: Thanks, I already found the solution, I just changed `columnFooter` to `groupFooter` band and it worked as I wanted.