# Jasper report template related issue with columnFooter

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a requirement where I need to have a template design in certain way that I can print few info section on first page only and few info would be dynamic and will continue on other pages. Here is the design I have

- `[Page Header]` will be repeated on each page
- `[column header]` will    print only on first page
- `[detail band]` will have dynamic table    which will expand to
  multiple page based on the table rows
- `[column    footer]` have info which I need only on page one
- `[page footer]` will    be displayed on each page
- `[Last page footer]` will have some    different info which will be
  on the last page only

My issue is that everyone thing is working but [column footer] is causing a problem. Column footer is printing the value on first page but occupying blank space on the other pages and because of that other pages have information printed on half page and half page is blank.

I saw the info in Jasper that column footer will not be collapsed. What is the solution to fix this issue.

Please give some suggestions for it.

As my requirements are little different then given solution. Here is I explain

1. The information which I have in `ColumnFooter` should be on first page only.
2. Above the `ColumnFooter` I have detail band which contains a table. The table in detail band is dynamic and it can have any number of rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the Column Footer band dynamically hide in Jasper report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886140/how-to-make-the-column-footer-band-dynamically-hide-in-jasper-report)

Comment: use groupFooter instead as suggested in the duplicate

Comment: The issue with group footer is that it will print the data after detail band's content is printed. I have detail band with dynamic table which can go to next page based on the data but the content in `ColumnFooter` should be in first page only.

Comment: GroupHeader prints info about detail band. I need info after detail band.

Comment: Ahh sorry I did not understand your comment. If group per page don't you get a group footer on each page? Are you using the jr:table?

Comment: @Petter Friberg yes I am using jr:table. I have detail band with jr:table which is dynamic. below the detail band I have ColumnFooter band which should be on first page only. The column footer has PrintWhen expression to print it on first page but on the other pages ColumnFooter is occupying space and causing jr:table to render in half page and leaving half page blank.

Answer (score 0):

set the printWhenExpression property of Column footer

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
```

Comment: I already have "Print When" expression for page 1 and still it is occupying band width on the other page.

Comment: how to appear table on 1st page